# Interface parameter null

Tags: java

In my scenario i have use `Cache_Categories()` Method many places but some time not need to override `After_Success()` method it is possible calling method without override `After_Success()` method without Overloading

Interface :

```
 public interface Web_Service
    {
        public void After_Success();
    }
```

Method :

```
public static void Cache_Categories(Web_Service i)
    { 
    i.After_Success();
    }
```

Call :
usually

```
 new App_Methods().Cache_Categories(this, false, new App_Methods.Web_Service()
        {
            @Override
            public void After_Success()
            {

            }
        });
```

Wanted :

```
new App_Methods().Cache_Categories(this, false,null);
```

Comment: java-8 has capability to do this. kindly follow java-8 feature's default method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if webService is null and do not call it's method.

Answer (score 1):

If you used Java 8 then you could change:

```
public static void Cache_Categories(SomeType type, Boolean b, Web_Service i)
    { 
         i.After_Success();
    }
```

to

```
public static void Cache_Categories(SomeType type, Boolean b, Optional<Web_Service> i)
    { 
         i.ifPresent(Web_Service::After_Success);
    }
```

in this case you just call:

```
 new App_Methods().Cache_Categories(this, false, Optional.ofNullable(ws));
```

when `ws` could be parameter, local var, object property and could be null.

Answer (score 0):

Change the interface to an abstract class.

```
public abstract class Web_Service
{
    public abstract void after_Success();
}
```

Comment: and method names should start with lowercase letter